# Getting user data from firebase using Promise instead of Observable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I used the Observer pattern to get the logged-in user data from firebase in my react project. Using the observer pattern makes more sense. Here's the piece of code that I wrote using the observer pattern.

```
unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

componentDidMount() {

    // subscribing

    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
          setCurrentUser({
            currentUser: {
              id: snapShot.id,
              ...snapShot.data(),
            },
          });
        });
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
       
        addCollectionAndDocuments(
          "collections",
          collectionsArray.map(({ title, items }) => ({ title, items }))
        );
      }
    });
  }
componentWillUnmount() {

   //unsubscribing

    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }
```

But I thought it was a good idea to move this piece inside the firebase utils and use that method in redux-saga code. So I decided to refactor this code like below

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      unsubscribeFromAuth(); // what is this function doing?
      resolve(userAuth); // what is resolve doing in this line
    }, reject);
  });
};
```

Though the above pieces of code do the same thing I don't understand the promise-based function. Can someone explain the promise based function?

Comment: Why this question gets downvoted? What's the meaning of this?

Comment: You should specified the exact problem that you have and wants others to help you with solving it. You question is about explaining how things works without showing exact problem that you facing. SO it's not place for it. That's my guess.

Comment: I explained the portion of code briefly and then questioned my doubt, what's wrong with that? Answering takes patience, so does posting a question and making other users understand what I'm trying to say. If he/she doesn't have that, I don't know what to say @ulou

Comment: Thats was just my guess. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with `rxjs Observables` `onAuthStateChanged` kinda works like `BehaviorSubject`.

Whenever user auth data changes `onAuthStateChanged` function constantly updates us with that value.

But when we are converting it to a promise we are asking it to just give the latest value of user auth. [Fetching the latest `userAuth` value using a `Promise`]

So, we are connecting (`subscribing`) to the updates by `auth.onAuthStateChanged()`
function then getting the latest `userAuth` and immediately disconnecting from it which is what `unsubscribeFromAuth` function does. If `unsubscribeFromAuth` is not called then we will have memory leaks in our app. Since we are opening/subscribing to a stream of information but we are just getting the latest value and not closing the connection (`Unsubscribing`). So that stream goes on in-memory in the background even if you are not using the stream updates

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      unsubscribeFromAuth(); // This function is unsubscribing to authStateChanges once we get the latest value of userAuth
      resolve(userAuth); // when you call resolve with a value -> The promise returns that value
    }, reject);
  });
};
```

Also please take a look at the promise [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

You will understand resolve and reject better.

Comment: so basically you're saying to remove the onAuthStateChange listener, we are calling the unsubscribeFromAuth again to stop listening right?

Comment: Yes. you are right.